# Book Reference - Zend Framework integration with Javascript Frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Is there any good book reference that show us the relation between our Zend Application and Javascript Frameworks - What design patterns are in place here, what are our options ?

I'm asking this because ZendX will be dropped, and will no longer be available on future ZF versions (at least not in the next one).

Despite all the bad things, it has indeed, make a heavy lifting for us, on integrating all those things together. Now however, that will no longer be the case.

So, is there any good book, resource that we can look at in order to understand the possibilities from here ?

Comment: don't think you will find any yet, basically because ZendX is not dropped yet. Cant write book for something in the future unless you are a sci-fi writer. Furthermore Zend is being developed too fast for the writers to catch up with the latest version changes. All you would probably need is to write your own jsfw loaders and make some decorators and changes in the view scripts i avoid using ZendX, because it rarely work well without custom code. What Zend are trying is to clean up the code from any wrappers that does not add functionality.

Comment: @venimus: My question doesn't ask for a book that talks about ZendX drop off. My question is about finding a book that share with us the foundations of integrating Zend Framework with a Javascript Library. No matter how. But perhaps there isn't any, mainly because, as you said, Zend Framework is constantly changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is some "plug and go" solution for this. But Zend offers the viewHelpers and placeholders. With those and a bit of OO magic you can create anything yourself. The JS code is in most cases highly customized, so there is little-to-no need for specific classes in Zend for this.

"Zend way" is that there are tools ready for you for practically any task, but there are no ready to use templates and you're encouraged to create (and share) them yourselves.

**Edit:**

IMHO there is one way that is kind-of encouraged. And that is to use the ContextSwitch action helper (@see manual) and Json action helper extensively.

For structuring your code - as far the JS code goes - it's not Zend's business. But I would suggest having a folder /js and subfolders for module-specific js files (/js/admin/). Then some generic folder with libraries (/js/lib/jquery/) and filenames using the jqery plugin filenames (library.name-of-plugin.js - jquery.autocomplete.js).

For handling repetitive tasks (like switching status - enabled/disabled) via JS you should use action helper. Then you just create new action:

```
public function statusAction()
{
    $this->_helper->switchStatus->process(this->_$request);
}

//in helper
public function process($request)
{
    //handle the request like you would in the action (simplified)
    $this->_actionController->model->switchStatus($request->getParam('id'));
    $this->_helper->json(array('result' => 'success'));
}
```

Comment: My doubts are related not so much with code but with code organization and, as well, ways to deal with ajax calls. Perhaps, and by taking what you said, a general book related a server language and this ajax thing, may give me what I need and then, I can pass that to Zend. For example, I will need to develop a jquery autocomplete, then, what classes and where, should I create them? Or let's say that, another ui widget is our thing, where should we put it, how should we integrate it on a well organized way.. I'm aware that I can even called them on the view but, will it be ok? ..

Comment: (cont) I understand that each case is it's case, but I'm sure patterns may exist as well. :)

Comment: It's a start. :) Thanks a lot.